# private static fields, should names start with underscore?

Tags: java

I came across a list of naming convensions, wondering how I should name my non-final private static fields. Link [**here**](http://www.appperfect.com/support/java-coding-rules/namingconvention.html#rule38), Rule #38.

The resource states that **non-final private static variable names should start with an underscore**.

However, I have personally never come across any Java-code where this rule is enforced.
Is this bogus, or should I adhere to it?

Comment: that is totally left to you.. As long as the name makes sense... I personally prefer "not-using" underscore.. i suggest camelCase...

Comment: Such syntactical standards are highly subjective, and I have seen production codebases adhering to that and others not. This question will likely be closed.

Comment: I'm going to say it: non-final private static variables should not exist in the first place.  Mutable static variables are dangerous.

Comment: You're asking us if someone's opinion about a naming style is bogus or not. That question does not have an objective answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'd avoid having non-final static fields, then you don't have to think about naming them as well.

If you still need them, don't use the underscore.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such [standard convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). In fact, the convention asks you not to start your variable names with *underscore* or *dollar*, even though it is allowed.

Moreover, it is just a personal preference. The project that you work on might follow some different conventions, that differ from the standard conventions.

Answer (score 2):

I have never approved of leading-underscore naming conventions.
It could be a throwback to C style conventions that some folks just couldn't let go of.

The industry standard is to name them "normally" (as you would any variable name).

Answer (score 0):

There is no [official](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) naming convention that states that a field should start with an underscore.

However, it is often used to make it clear in code which is a local variable and which is a `private static` variable. An alternative method is to make sure `ClassName.` is used when referencing said variables, or keeping them all in CAPS.

Answer (score 0):

Refering to Java there are "official" [code conventions by Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html). But as any convention there are not obligatory. They are just conventions and kind of a matter of personal preference. The important thing in my opinion is, that you agree upon some convention in the team. Which one that is doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

In Java camelCase without underscore fields is the actual "Convention", however, in many projects I see the C/C# convention of underscoring your fields to be able to differ between class variables / instance variables and local variables.